# Can we have two or more function call in jquery-ajax success

Tags: javascript, html, xml, jquery

I have request to webservice and getback xml result as output , In sucess function can i have a two or more function call

```
function searchLocationNear() {
    // Get the radius using jQuery
    var radius = $("#radiusSelect").val();

    // Make Ajax call using jQuery
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      data: "keyword1=&streetname=&lat=&lng=&radius=" + radius,
      url: "WebService1.asmx/GetList",
      success: function (response) {
        var xml = GXml.parse(response.xml);
        ....
        .....
        var marker=createmarker(...........);
        var sidebar cretesidebar(.........);      


      },
      error: function (response) {
        alert(response);
      }
    });
  }
function createmarker(..........)
{}
function createsidebar(....)
{
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can. Don't forget the assignment symbol `var sidebar = cretesidebar(...);`